# MySQL Error: #1142 - TRIGGER command denied

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-grant

I need that my MySQL database makes a sum of some values in a specific coloumn. To do that I used trigger statement but MySQL gave me an error:

> MySQL Error: #1142 - TRIGGER comand denied to user 'XXXXXX' for table wp_wpdatatable_8

the Trigger is below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SumPliche AFTER INSERT ON wp_wpdatatable_8 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE wp_wpdatatable_8 SET sommapliche = tricipite + addome + soprailiaca + sottoscapolare + ascellare + pettorale + coscia
```

How can I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems the issue here is with the permissions your user has on the database from which `wp_wpdatatable_8`.

To grant trigger permissions for a specific user and database, you may use the following command:

```
mysql> GRANT TRIGGER ON <DATABASE>.* TO <USER>@'<DATABASE HOST>';
```

Where

- `<DATABASE>` refers to the database that contains the `wp_wpdatatable_8` table.
- `<USER>` the username that is trying to issue the `CREATE TRIGGER` command.
- `<DATABASE HOST>` database host from where your user accesses the database. If you are running it locally, you can use `localhost`.

After flushing the privileges, creating the trigger should work normally.

For more information, check out the [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) syntax on the MySQL.documentation

Comment: Good answer, but FYI there's no need to use FLUSH PRIVILEGES. GRANT or REVOKE does this automatically. Only if you use INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE directly on the system tables do you need FLUSH PRIVILEGES. There is no harm in using FLUSH PRIVILEGES, but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You lack the TRIGGER privilege on the database you are using.

I got this error when I did a test. Create a test user:

```
mysql> create user 'bill'@'localhost';
mysql> grant all privileges on test2.* to 'bill'@'localhost';
mysql> revoke trigger on test2.* from 'bill'@'localhost';
mysql> show grants for 'bill'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for bill@localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'bill'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*29A1BB43D3B9EB42028B4566E4836353285B9395'                                                                                                                  |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT ON `test2`.* TO 'bill'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now try creating a trigger as this user:

```
~ mysql -ubill -p
mysql> use test2
mysql> create table t ( i int);
mysql> create trigger tt before insert on t for each row set new.i = 42;
ERROR 1142 (42000): TRIGGER command denied to user 'bill'@'localhost' for table 't'
```

I also think your trigger might not do what you think it does, so it's just as well that you didn't create it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SumPliche AFTER INSERT ON wp_wpdatatable_8 
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE wp_wpdatatable_8 
  SET sommapliche = tricipite + addome + soprailiaca + sottoscapolare + ascellare + pettorale + coscia
```

If I create this trigger in my test database (as a different user with TRIGGER privilege), and then try to insert a row:

```
mysql> insert into wp_wpdatatable_8 values (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'wp_wpdatatable_8' in 
stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked 
this stored function/trigger.
```

You probably want to set values only in the row you insert. If so, you would reference the current row being inserted with the `NEW.*` syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SumPliche BEFORE INSERT ON wp_wpdatatable_8 
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.sommapliche = NEW.tricipite + NEW.addome + NEW.soprailiaca 
    + NEW.sottoscapolare + NEW.ascellare + NEW.pettorale + NEW.coscia;
```

Also you must use `BEFORE INSERT` if you want to change a value in the row before you insert it. If you use `AFTER INSERT`, it's too late.

Now it works:

```
mysql> insert into wp_wpdatatable_8 values (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from wp_wpdatatable_8;
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| sommapliche | tricipite | addome | soprailiaca | sottoscapolare | ascellare | pettorale | coscia |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|           7 |         1 |      1 |           1 |              1 |         1 |         1 |      1 |
+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```